# Desativa função de collapse do DataTables

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

Boas! Precisava de saber se existe maneira de impedir o DataTables de dar collapse às colunas, e também se existe alguma maneira de além de usar o columns.visible para tornar a coluna invisivel, mas que também não ocupe espaço!

Para mais fácil compreensão:

Este é o que eu quero que aconteça sempre:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém por vezes o datatables faz isto, pondo a coluna Operations em um td child...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Você pode desabilitar esse comportamento com a configuração "responsive", setando a opção "details" como `false`. Fica assim, na configuração do DataTable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tabela').DataTable( {
      //... outras configurações
      responsive: {
          details: false
      }
  } );
} );
```

Dessa forma as childs não aparecerão, mas se quiser mostrá-las por padrão, a configuração é essa:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tabela').DataTable( {
      responsive: {
          details: {
              display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.childRowImmediate,
              type: ''
          }
      }
    });
});
```